# Form is closing instead of performing function when i press close button

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

In my project I am using two forms `dialogForm` and `mainForm`.

In `mainForm` I am calling the instance of the `dialogForm` something like this:

**mainForm_Closing Event**

```
private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    dialogForm dg = new dialogForm();
    dg.Show();
}
```

But in the above code, the `mainForm` is closing when I press close button and showing the `dialogForm` instead of even showing the `mainForm`.

I know I am doing something wrong here.

PS: I edited my question very much. If someone were working with my code then [here it is](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/87374848/SuperMarketApp%201026.rar).

Comment: Please post your code here (only the relevant parts) instead of linking to other sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `dg.Show()` instead of `dg.ShowDialog()`. `ShowDialog()` will wait for the child dialog box to close before continuing to execute the instructions in the parent dialog box.

Return a value from the dialogForm and check if it is yes or no, and depending on that close the parent box.